# Sometime not get response from OneSignal when i try to get deviceId in Android

Tags: android, onesignal

I am using "OneSignal.idsAvailable()" method to get deviceId. Sometimes I get a response but sometimes not. It throws following exception:

```
OneSignalRestClient: null Error thrown from network stack. 
java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
at com.android.okhttp.okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:145)
at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:78)
at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:221)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.flush(HttpConnection.java:141)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.finishRequest(HttpTransport.java:60)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:1147)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:980)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:482)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:418)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:540)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient.startHTTPConnection(OneSignalRestClient.java:146)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient.access$100(OneSignalRestClient.java:38)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient$4.run(OneSignalRestClient.java:94)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think due to network issue its reaching to the timeout. You should when you request the device ids, check internet connection first and then request the device id.

Comment: I have checked there is no internet issue.